# Struggling with SwiftUi Assignment

Tags: swiftui

1. How do I fix this error? I'm trying to have Ticks and Crosses. The Error will be Listed below.
   [image]
2. I need to create a "Show all Completed tasks" Sliding button, in which will display the "Ticked" tasks.

note: don't mind the "contacts" variables and functions as it was originally a contacts assignment.

I've tried adding brackets around bits of code.

Here's my Pastebin With all the code:
https://pastebin.com/BpvWSVpP
By the way, the error is in the complete:bool

Cannot convert value of type 'Bool.Type' to expected argument type 'Bool'

```
let newContact = Contact( id: UUID().uuidString, firstName: self.firstName, 
    lastName: self.lastName, complete: Bool)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. All your code should be inside the question (not a link to an external site) and you should provide the smallest possible version of code that demonstrates the issue you're having. That being said, what you want is to change `complete: Bool` to `complete: false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class `Contact` needs a `Bool`, not a type declaration.

```
var complete = false

...

let newContact = Contact(id: UUID().uuidString, firstName: self.firstName, 
lastName: self.lastName, complete: complete)
```